# how to check connection is closed by server or server supports keep alive?

Tags: httprequest, keep-alive

**how can I check that server supports keep-alive ?**
I want to check this by analyzing http response.
I am using mongoose c++ server. and I am setting header keep-alive. 
But I doubt it is closing the connection. As it is always taking time **required to connect to host from client**. I doubt connection is getting close.

How I can check that connection is getting closed or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "close" takes place on the TCP level - so IMHO the most relaibale place to check for it is the network level - you can check that by using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)...

Comment: Yes, using Fiddler, you can look at the Timeline tab to see if Connections are being reused.